# Giving subviews higher priority over parent view?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

In IB, I configure an NSView that's presented as a popover view programmatically, but internal content may vary thus causing internal size change.

Currently, if the size of any element changes, auto layout doesn't adjust the size of the popover, I actually had the opposite issues a few days ago where I didn't want subviews to change window size, I solved it by changing subviews compression resistance, I thought augmenting compression resistance might solve the issue, but it didn't.

How to let subviews resize their parent view?

Comment: @matt Thank you ! It’s surprising that there is no automatic way for this :/

Comment: @matt Isn't that the case for NSWindow too tough ? For instance if you add an NSTextView and set it's constraints so that it has a certain distance to left, right and bottom of it's superview, the window will resize when you update the content, in an other situation I din't want this behavior but I felt that it would make sense to make this possible in a popover.

Comment: @matt Actually hadn't set some constraints, but I discovered that the popover does in fact resize as would NSWindow

Comment: Cool! Makes sense. I'll delete my comments. You might actually answer your own question: could help someone down the road...

Comment: @matt I will ! Thank you for your help. Unfortunately there is now a weird temporary glitch when size changes.